# Filling collection A according to collection B

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections in c#

```
A: {
      {id:4, name:"", age:1},
      {id:3, name:"", age:3},
      {id:2, name:"", age:5},
}

B: {
      {id:2, name:"aa"},
      {id:4, name:"bb"},
      {id:3, name:"cc"},
}
```

I want to fill collection A according to collection B

```
A: {
      {id:2, name:"aa",age:5},
      {id:4, name:"bb",age:1},
      {id:3, name:"cc",age:3},
}
```

How can I do this?
(should I use linq?)

I used:

```
   private static void FillIsCpHidden(ref Collection A)
        {
            var B= CollectionB.ToDictionary(item => item.id);

            foreach (var item in A)
            {
                item.name= B[item.id].name;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You want to set name vales on A from B? Your question is a little short..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from B

```
var dictB = B.ToDictionary(b=>b.id);
```

Then you create a new list.

```
var c = A.Select(a=>new{ a.id, name=dictB[a.Id].name,a.age   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**I would youse LINQ to solve this problem:**

```
    var d = (from i in A select new { id = i.id, age=i.age, 
name = (from b in B where b.id == i.id select b.name).SingeleOrDefault()}).ToList();
```

**Another possibility without creating a new variable:**

```
  A =  A.Select(d=>new{ d.id, name=a=>new{ a.id, name=dictB[a.Id].name,d.age})
```

Comment: would it be waste to allocate new items, just to fill one field?

Comment: @EladBenda I've added an alternative without creating an new variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Linq

```
 var collectionB = collectionA.Select(p=>new B() { id=p.id, name=p.name});
```

or

```
var collectionA = collectionB.Select(p=>new A() { id=p.id, name=p.name});
```

Comment: would it be waste to allocate new items, just to fill one field?

Answer (score 0):

You could use joins:

```
var result = a.Join(b,
                    o => o.Id,
                    i => i.Id,
                    (o, i) => new { o.Id, i.Name, o.Age });
```